# Titles and NSLog not running in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nslog

I can't seem to understand why I can't display the title and subtitle for my cell. I've tried getting the string objects through `NSLog()`, but I don't receive any output aside from the `NSLog()` that successfully prints the memory location of the test object ( a `Stack` object) in the array, `array_Stacks`.

here is my `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SimpleCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SimpleCell"];
    }

    NSString *cell_Title = [[array_Stacks objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] title];
    NSString *cell_Subtitle = [[array_Stacks objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] subject];

    NSLog(@"%@", cell_Title);

    NSLog(@"%@", [array_Stacks objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]]);
    NSLog(@"%@", cell_Subtitle);

    cell.textLabel.text = cell_Title;
    cell.textLabel.tintColor = [cp color_master_tan];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = cell_Subtitle;
    cell.detailTextLabel.tintColor = [cp color_master_tan];
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"asset_Cell"];

    return cell;
}
```

Note: "cp" is my color palette object and is returning a `UIColor` object.

Here is Stack.m

```
#import "Stack.h"
#import "FlashCard.h"

/*
 Notes

 * Need to get the name of the creator and add it to the default init.

 */

@implementation Stack
{
    NSMutableArray *array_flashCard;
}
@synthesize title, subject, creator, array_FlashCard;

#pragma mark - Initializers

- (id)init {
    return [self initWithTitle:@"New Stack" subject:@"No Subject" creator:@"None Listed" array:array_FlashCard];
}

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *) ttl subject:(NSString *) sbj creator:(NSString *) ctr array:(NSMutableArray *) arr {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        title = ttl;
        subject = sbj;
        creator = ctr;
        array_FlashCard = arr;

        title = [[NSString alloc] init];
        subject = [[NSString alloc] init];
        creator = [[NSString alloc] init];
        array_FlashCard = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Array Operations

- (void)addFlashCardToArray:(FlashCard *) flashcard { [array_FlashCard addObject:flashcard]; }

@end
```

Comment: The strings are empty.

Comment: First, is it being called at all?  Set a breakpoint and see if it gets triggered.  If not, what have you set as the table view's data source?  Does your method get called that says how many rows are in the table?  If so, what does it return?

Comment: The 2nd NSLog prints out the correct information which is a memory address for the Stack object in the array, so I know the object exists and that the method is getting triggered. File's owner is set. Problem is, even if the strings were empty, I would at least be getting 'nil' with a timestamp in the terminal, but I don't get anything.

Comment: No, the strings are valid objects, but they're empty. `nil` is not the same as an empty string, and `NSLog()` will not print anything if all you give it is an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting your strings to `@""` in your `Stack initWithTitle:...`.

```
    title = ttl;
    subject = sbj;
    creator = ctr;
    array_FlashCard = arr;

    title = [[NSString alloc] init]; // Throw away previous value; assign new empty string.
    subject = [[NSString alloc] init]; // Throw away previous value; assign new empty string.
    creator = [[NSString alloc] init]; // Throw away previous value; assign new empty string.
    array_FlashCard = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // Throw away previous value; assign new empty array.
```

Comment: This did it. Im still not sure why I'm not getting a timestamp with a nil for the other two NSLogs but now my titles show up. Thanks!

Comment: Again, @Cole, the strings are _valid objects_, not `nil`. An empty string is not the same as `nil`.

Answer (score -1):

The thing that you have to understand that it's just a small mistake in most of the cases. So, you have to check the following thing.

1. Whether the delegate and data source are set up properly. And set the break point whether the delegation methods are called properly.
2. Whether the data source is not returning zero object. Because the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will not be called if the data source contains no objects.

Hope this helps and trust me it's not something serious. You might probably just miss something.

And the weird thing is you already assign `title`, `subject`, `creator` and `array_FlashCard`. But you initialize it again so they become empty anymore.